# Length contraction of a square moving along the diagonal

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

The problem:
A square is moving with velocity $v$ in the direction of one of its diagonals. What is the length contraction of the square for someone who is at rest.

My line of thought was that we can resolve $v$ into $v_x$ and $v_y$, which have equal magnitude. Because of that, the horizontal and vertical contractions will be equal and we will get a smaller square.

However, I researched the question online and it said everywhere that you don't get a smaller square, because only one diagonal contracts while the other stays the same length because it is perpendicular to the direction of motion.

I understand the logic behind this approach, but I don't understand why my approach is wrong. And they can't both be right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The mistake you made was assuming that length contraction is a linear operation.

By linear here I mean in the mathematical sense. Length contraction is an operation that takes a position (or length) and a velocity and gives us a different position. $\vec{x}' = f(\vec{x},\vec{v})$. A linear operation would mean that $f(\vec{x}, \vec{v}_1+\vec{v}_2) = f(\vec{x},\vec{v}_1) + f(\vec{x},\vec{v}_2)$. That is, the result of length contraction based on the sum of two velocities is the same as the sum of two individual length contractions.

But, as the formula Dale wrote shows, the length contraction formula is not linear in this way. Many important operations in physics end up being linear, but length contraction is not one of them! It is important to learn not to assume that any given operation is linear.

Answer (score 9):

> My line of thought was that we can resolve v into vx and vy, which have equal magnitude. Because of that, the horizontal and the vertical contractions will be equal and we will get a smaller square.

The first sentence is correct. However, the second sentence is wrong. If you are going to treat $\vec v$ as a vector with components $\vec v = (v_x,v_y)= |\vec v|\ \hat v$ then you need to use the [vector form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#Vector_transformations) of the Lorentz transform. $$t'=\gamma\left(t-\frac{\vec v \cdot \vec r}{c^2}\right)$$$$\vec r'=\vec r + (\gamma-1)(\vec r \cdot \hat v)\hat v - \gamma t \vec v$$

If you use this correct form of the Lorentz transform for a vector velocity, then you will also get a diamond.

It would be incorrect to apply two successive Lorentz boosts, as the composition of two non-colinear Lorentz boosts is not a Lorentz boost, but rather a spatial rotation and a Lorentz boost. This is called [Wigner rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_rotation).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the other answers have adequately explained this. It's true, as Dale said, that a diagonal boost is the composition of a horizontal and vertical boost and a rotation, but if you apply the length contraction formula twice and then rotate the result, you still won't get the correct answer. (You'll get a rotated rectangle instead of a diamond/rhombus.)

The real problem is that you aren't thinking fourth-dimensionally—although in this problem, there are only two spatial dimensions, so you only have to think third-dimensionally, which is much easier.

The object in this problem is not a square, but a square cylinder (the world-tube of the square). Imagine it as an ordinary Euclidean cylinder for the moment. If its long direction is oriented vertically, a horizontal slice through it is a square. If you rotate it in the zx plane (say z is the vertical axis, x and y are horizontal), then take a horizontal slice through it, you'll get a rectangle that's lengthened in the x direction.

```
|     |        /                    z
|     |       /      /              ^
|<-L->|      /<-L'->/     L' > L    |
|     |     /      /                +---> x
|     |    /      /
                 /
```

If you instead rotate it in the zy plane, you'll get a rectangle lengthened in the y direction. But if you rotate it in the zx and then the zy plane, the cross section will not be a square that is larger along both axes. It will be a parallelogram of some sort.

The reason is that you're rotating the cylinder, not the cross-section. After the first rotation, you don't have a vertical cylinder with a rectangular cross section. You have a diagonal cylinder that's really still a square cylinder, and only looks rectangular because you're slicing it at a funny angle. The rule for what happens to the cross-section after a rotation depends on the whole cylinder, not just the last cross-section.

A Lorentz boost in the x direction is a rotation in the tx plane. Because of the −+++ metric signature, you get $L'<L$ instead of $L'>L$, but otherwise the geometry is very similar. The length contraction formula is a special case that only works if the "cylinder" is "vertical" before the rotation, so you can't apply it twice in a row.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a suggestion, which may or may not help:
Take a square and move it in the direction along one of its sides. That seems to be a situation you are comfortable with. Such as the gray square below (if you want concrete measurements to work with, it is 512 times 512 pixels):

[image: A gray, square image]

Now *draw a smaller square* inside the large square, angled $45^\circ$, with the corners of the drawing hitting the midpoints of the sides of the big square, like in the image below:

[image: Image of a square-in-square, the smaller square tilted 45 degrees]

Now, as the larger square is transformed exactly the way you're used to, maybe it's easier to visualize what is going to happen with the diagonal square?